# undefined method `rspec_reset' with rspec version 2.14

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mocking

I am trying execute test cases with rspec version 2.14 for which I am getting following error

```
undefined method `rspec_reset' for
```

I am trying to use rspec_reset on the class. The same test cases are working with rspec 2.13.1. So is it possible that rspec_reset method is not available after 2.13?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, in 2.14, `rspec_reset` is no longer available on all objects as it was previously, as discussed in https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/pull/250.

Although I can't find any documentation on it, there now appears to be an `RSpec` class method `reset` which takes an object as an argument and will effectively "undo" any RSpec operations that have been done to that object.

There's an RSpec "example" at https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/blob/cee433c89125a3984df33c87eb61985613adce9b/spec/rspec/mocks/mock_spec.rb which still uses the `rspec_reset` in the description of the example, but which now uses the aforementioned `reset` method to do the reset. In earlier versions of the example, the reset was done with `rspec_reset`.

Answer (score 16):

The `reset` method does not exist in RSpec 2.14.x. Instead, it is a helper method defined inside the **spec_helper.rb** file for the rspec-mocks project.

```
module VerifyAndResetHelpers
  def verify(object)
    RSpec::Mocks.proxy_for(object).verify
  end

  def reset(object)
    RSpec::Mocks.proxy_for(object).reset
  end
end
```

You can see that this method delegates the reset action to the underlying proxy instead of tacking it on to the class definition of the object in question.